# How to create custom template suggestion, when there is no hook suggestion?

Tags: 7, theming, hooks, quiz

I would like to create different templates for different nodes, but I cannot see any hook suggestion with theme debug. This is the template from quiz module.
So in theme debug it looks like that:

```
<!-- THEME DEBUG -->
<!-- CALL: theme('multichoice_alternative') -->
<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'sites/all/modules/contrib/quiz/question_types/multichoice/theme/multichoice-alternative.tpl.php' -->
```

I was searching for the right answer, reading about template suggestions, trying different things, but without any luck so far.
I know, that I can create custom template for the whole block, but is it possible to create that custom template for the element which doesn't have any hook suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

1. implement `hook_theme_registry_alter` like the following:

```
    /**
     * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
     */
    function YourCostumModuleName_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
      // Defined path to the current module.
      $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'YourCostumModuleName') . "/templates";
      // Find all .tpl.php files in this module's folder recursively.
      $template_file_objects = drupal_find_theme_templates($theme_registry, '.tpl.php', $module_path);
      // Iterate through all found template file objects.
      foreach ($template_file_objects as $key => $template_file_object) {
        // If the template has not already been overridden by a theme.
        if (!isset($theme_registry[$key]['theme path']) || !preg_match('#/themes/#', $theme_registry[$key]['theme path'])) {
          // Alter the theme path and template elements.
          $theme_registry[$key]['theme path'] = $module_path;
          $theme_registry[$key] = array_merge($theme_registry[$key], $template_file_object);
          $theme_registry[$key]['type'] = 'module';
        }
      }
    }
```

2. Create Folder called `templates` inside your custom module folder.
3. Copy `contrib/quiz/question_types/multichoice/theme/multichoice-alternative.tpl.php` file into `templates` folder with the same name `multichoice-alternative.tpl.php`.
4. `Clear Cache`.
5. Now you have `$form` and `$fullOptions` variables.